How to send stream data as a response in Python FastAPI?
I am able to get streaming data. I am using python FastAPI. How can I send the streaming data as a response and use it in front-end. I am struck at this position right now. This is the code:
Streaming code
@app.get("/streaming/{symbol}")
async def getStreamingQuoteBySymbol(symbol):
    try:
        client = schwab.auth.client_from_token_file(token_path=token_path, api_key=API_KEY, app_secret=API_SECRET)
        streamClient = schwab.streaming.StreamClient(client=client, account_id=ACCOUNT_ID)

        async def read_stream():
            try:
                await streamClient.login()
                print("Login successfully")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Failed to login streaming api.")

            def print_message(message):
                data = json.dumps(message, indent=4)
                print(data)
                print()

            streamClient.add_level_one_equity_handler(print_message)

            await streamClient.level_one_equity_subs([symbol])
            while True:
                await streamClient.handle_message()
            
        return StreamingResponse(await read_stream())

    
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error message: ", e)
        return { "status": "failed to stream" }


You shouldn't await the async generator you're giving to StreamingResponse - that just means that it'll read the whole generator before actually doing what you expect it to. You're not actually returning anything as your response either, so no data will be returned (you might want to yield something back to the client.

So, you means I need to remove async/await from read_stream() function? BTW its a sample code from Schwab API. From where I should yield the data? there are two section one is infinite loop and another one is print_message(). Funtion print_message() actually printing the streaming data here.

Does this answer your question? Related answers that might prove helpful to you should be found here, as well as here and here
